# Perlin Noise Image Creation In C#

Tags: c#, .net, image, picturebox, perlin-noise

i've seen so many examples for perlin noise out there, but they all where slightly diferent.

i'm wondering how i can use perlin noise algorythm to create an image in c#.

i would like to have a function that every time i call it, generates a new image and places it in a picturebox.

i've looked the perlin noise pseudo code, but i got confused. i want to be able to  manipulate some attributes with user input.

but now my question:

how can i integrate perlin noise into c# function that returns bitmap data ( 2d ) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
        Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(200, 200);

        for (int x = 0; x < 200; x++)
        {
            for (int y = 0; y < 200; y++)
            {
                int calc = (int)(((SimplexNoise.Noise.Generate(x, y)+1)/2)*255);
                bmp.SetPixel(x, y, Color.FromArgb(calc, calc, calc));
            }
        }
```

I was using https://code.google.com/p/simplexnoise/ but you can use any noise generator.

I hope this helps

Comment: thx for the advise, but isn't this just making a noisemap ? i should have said that i'd like to get a "heightmap" like grayscale image.

Comment: yes this creates a greyscale noisemap. this is what you start off with. then you have to interpolate it in order to make it smother. place a sealevel by setting every value below the sealevel to the sealevel. and so on. Since I'm quite bored right now I'd write a class capable off doing this for you if you are interested

Comment: yes of course, this would help me a lot ! i've never worked with noise map generation befor, and i'd love to experiment with this technique.

Comment: ( btw. you could email me if you want, i'm german too, so we could communicate much easyer. ace-acid@hotmail.de )